# Camera2 swapping Front & back side on-the-fly

Tags: java, android, api, camera, android-5.0-lollipop

In the new camera2 API, which are the right steps for swapping the front & back side cameras on-the-fly?

I've followed this [camera 2 exmple](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) and also try to add code for swapping between cameras. The camera works perfectly but I cannot find the right steps for swapping cameras and I always get a crash or the **camera is in use** error

In the pre-Lollipod API we had to release the camera.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: sorry but no solution so far